# add-apt-repository returns "Error: need a repository as argument" when adding a repo

Tags: installation, skype

when trying to install skype...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner”
Error: need a repository as argument
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you copy-pasted the command from your terminal, you're using the wrong quotes. Your code has asymmetric codes intended for typography: “opening and closing”. You need to use the symmetric double quote character from the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set, the one that you insert by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> on a US keyboard.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

If you copy-pasted the command from a tutorial, you're entitled to complain about the typesetting of that tutorial: it should ensure that characters in code snippets are not modified.